# How can I convert the time zone string "Europe/Amsterdam" to "CET-1CEST,M3.5.0/2,M10.5.0/3"?

Tags: java, android, timezone, posix

On an Android device, I need to convert the time zone Id

```
Europe/Amsterdam
```

to

```
CET-1CEST,M3.5.0/2,M10.5.0/3
```

Is it possible?

Is it a standard (posix)?

Comment: If you did that, you'd be throwing away [all history before 1977](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/3e885e21d9b5f6e3913d46ed457ce9236a020eef/europe#L1862-L1867).  That may be ok for your scenario, but you should be aware that they are not equivalent.  You'd also be locking your self out of potential *future* changes if any were to be made.   See also the section on POSIX style time zones in [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Comment: @MattJohnson Thanks for your suggestions. I need to set the time zone of the Carambola 2 board (http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/8devices/carambola2) and it accepts the posix format. So do you confirm there's no automatic conversion utility to convert tz id's to posix in Java?

Comment: I can't confirm that, hence the comment rather than answer.  Technically, it's not possible to convert an *entire* time zone, but you could project the *current* rule to the POSIX format - as long as there is only one DST period considered.  (Some zones such as `Africa/Cairo` and `Africa/Casablanca` have had *two* DST periods in a single year - which POSIX cannot represent.)  I'm sure somone could give an answer here showing how to use Java to project a single POSIX rule from an IANA zone.  There may even be a method built-in for that - I'm just not familiar enough to provide it.

Comment: @MattJohnson I'm planning to import all strings recognized by OpenWRT (carambola 2) into my Android project and pair to the standard time zone ids. Thanks for your help.

Comment: NP.  Do think about how you will keep it updated as well.  You may wish to subscribe to the Announcements list at [iana.org/time-zones](http://www.iana.org/time-zones) to stay on top of news of updates.

Comment: @MattJohnson Oh, yes, a good advice!

Comment: Little late to the party, but nevertheless https://remotemonitoringsystems.ca/time-zone-abbreviations.php